# textarea in gridview to new datatable column

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a gridview in which textareas are added for user input. The input data shall be added as columns to a datatable.
Right now, I'm foreach'ing through the whole datatable for output and textarea placing, how do I get the textarea values and add them in asp.net with codebehind c#?

Comment: Are you asking how to update single row, when someone inputs some value to textarea for corresponding row?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking. Sorry for not explaining it better.

Comment: How you are going to save the values, is it all at a once, lets say you have a button, that will save all textbox content to DB or it is just at row command, like save the single row only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

1. Accessing the GridView Row by Row to get the data of the textareas.
2. Placing them in a DataTable as new columns and rows.
3. Modify the DataTable of the Gridview to contain the columns of the textareas.
4. Using an iterator to insert the textarea data from the DataTable in the foreach loop of the other DataTable appending them at the end of the rows.